# Firebase authentication to Azure AD from Android app

Tags: android, firebase, azure, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add the "Microsoft" sign in method to my Firebase project, with the hope of allowing users to login to my Android app using their Azure AD credentials. I already have everything set up to use the "Email/Password" provider, which is working well.

I don't plan on accessing any Azure APIs, I just need to authenticate a given user so that when an organization terminates said users account, he is no longer able to login to my app.

I am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth this guide. I have registered an app on my Azure AD, set it to allow accounts from any organization as well as personal accounts, and added the client ID and secret to my Firebase project. I have also added the redirect url from the Firebase project to the App registration on Azure.

I start the login process using `startActivityForSignInWithProvider` like in the example. The chrome tab loads and takes me through the entire authentication process. **The problem is** this always returns a failure with the exception `Error: (invalid_client) AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented'`

This is confusing, since, in order to enable this sign-in provider on Firebase, you are required to enter the client ID and client secret.

I've tried with the app registration setting "Treat application as public client" set to Yes and No. I've also tried with a blank scopes collection and adding 'openId' to the scopes as a stab in the dark.

I'm a bit out of my depth with this Microsoft Authentication stuff, so any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the app in Azure as web app instead of Native App. Because the URL provided by Firebase is for Web App. Hope this helps.

Comment: Project was mothballed, so I doubt I'll test this but it does sound promising. Thanks!

Comment: I was also testing the same and came across your question. Initially I registered using native app and it wasn't working. Then I had a hunch that why a native client will have a https as scheme rather native clients usually use package name as scheme which is unique to them so tried with registering the client as web app and voila it works :) What I think is post login success it returns back to firebase redirect uri then in turn it returns back to the app.